# Laravel. What is the best practice to get model data from ElasticSearch?

Tags: php, laravel, rest, elasticsearch, search

What is the best way for mapping data and then retrieve it?

First is mapping all model fields, then create another Elasticsearch Repository and retrieve it fully from ElasticSearch. The problem here, is that you should dublicate your data and pass more data via requests.

As a second aproach, to map only searchable fields, retrieve models IDs from Elastic and then collect data from local database. But here you have to retrieve to many fields and make slow Where In requests to local DB.

Please, help me to understand what's the most common, practical aproach.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your problem or use case.

1. If its trivial for you to sync your changed data (in DB) with elasticsearch, or if synchronizing is not important for you then you can index and get all the data you need from elasticsearch itself.
   Otherwise, You can just index the searchable data and retrieve all the required (and latest) data from DB. This saves you the hassle of synchronizing all your changes to elasticsearch. Also, this might not be a big hassle depending on your problem.
2. Depending on the size of the data that you expect to store, and the cost for deploying elasticsearch. If data size is not an issue, you can just consider case 1.
3. I'd add more, but you get it.?

Comment: Thanks you. It helped me better understand.